# Is it possible use current stream functions inside stream function?

Tags: java

For example I have some string. I want split it by space and then filter only words that have length that is greater than stream count. See code below

```
Arrays.stream("Some important string".split(" "))
      .filter(word->word.length>([HOW GET HERE STREAM COUNT??]))
```

The task is do it in one line (without external variables)

Comment: Did you mean you  want to compare number of words with each word's length ?

Comment: Yes. Number of words is stream count in my case

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why would you call `new String()` with a `String` as parameter? Don't do that!!

Comment: 1. Find the count; 2. Filter words that have length > count

Comment: @Andreas I have other task. This is only as example and I forget delete it

Comment: The fact that you wrote that at all is baffling!!

Comment: @alex: The task as you have specified it is _not possible._  It cannot be done in one line without external variables, not without doing something that would allow other variables to be created.

Comment: @LouisWasserman To be frank we can do this by inserting  other stream that contains the same elements. But I thouth it can be easier

Comment: There is way `Stream.of("Some important string")
    .map(e -> e.split(" "))
    .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e).filter(w -> w.length() > e.length).collect(Collectors.toList())).findFirst().get()`

Comment: Like I said: not without doing something that would allow other variables to be created.  That solution is just a hack to define a new variable named `e` containing the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **hack**, and I would strongly discourage the use, but you can do it like this:

```java
String[] result = Stream.<String[]>of("Some important strings to test".split(" "))
        .flatMap(words -> Stream.of(words).filter(word -> word.length() > words.length))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

The code would be much better if you simply use a variable:

```java
String[] words = "Some important strings to test".split(" ");
String[] result = Stream.of(words)
        .filter(word -> word.length() > words.length)
        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

*Output from both*

```
[important, strings]
```

---

If the question is not about how to do it with an array returned by `split()`, but is actually the literal question **"how to get stream count"**, then the answer is that you can't.

Even if you had access to the stream, you couldn't call [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--), since that would *consume* the stream and defy the purpose of the call.

Comment: @fps Thank, so much better.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.

A stream can only be iterated over once, so if you call `.count()` on the stream you can no longer call `.filter()`.

Here's a kludgy example that uses `count()` on the stream in the expression that `filter()`s it:

```
Stream.of(Arrays.stream("Some important string".split(" ")))
   .map(s -> s.filter(x -> x.length() > s.count())).findAny().get().toArray();
```

And here's the predictable result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    stream has already been operated upon or closed
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
```